# Evaluate amount of available physical memory

Tags: c, malloc, ansi-c

First of all: my application does not run on a "normal" operating system with virtual memory or MMU or something like that, but on an embedded system with fixed and limited amount of physical memory.

So this question focuses on plain ANSI-C: when I do calls to malloc() the amount of available memory reduces by the allocated size. Is there an ANSI-C function which can be used to retrieve the amount of remaining, free memory?

Comment: No, and it's usually memory fragmentation that will cause `malloc` to fail before you actually run out of that last available byte.

Comment: "the amount of available memory reduces by the allocated size" ~ usually by *more than* the allocated size.

Comment: You can write your own malloc(?)

Comment: `embedded system with fixed and limited amount of physical memory.` If it is limited, you could know the limit. If you don't know: allocate all the memory you'll ever need at program start-up. If it fails: fail. If it doesn't fail: give it back and go ahead.

Comment: To begin with, [it doesn't make any sense to use malloc on resource-constrained embedded systems](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171257/realloc-wasting-lots-of-space-in-my-mcu/171581#171581).

Comment: Thanks for all the comments that do not have to do anything with the question I asked. I know that dynamic memory allocation is not a good idea on embedded systems. I want to use this function ONLY in debug mode and ONLY to verify if my calculations regarding memory usage are correct or if somewhere came something in between that was forgotten. So thanks for answering my question without any additional noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. ..............................